# Keep value data in form after submiting PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I have had a look at other posts but could not solve the issue.

I am trying to find what is the easiest way to keep form values after post. For example a registration form,

If a user enters all correct data except for one field (an email address for example) then the form gets submitted via a PHP form, how do I keep the valid form data but get rid of the data that is not valid?

Below is my form code:

```
<form action="./scripts/register.php" method="POST" name="registration" />
        Your Name: 
            <input class="submissionfield" type="text" name="name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+" title="Your name can only contain alphabetic characters" placeholder="Bob Smith"> 

        Username: &nbsp; 
            <input class="submissionfield" type="text" name="username" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" title="Username can only contain alphabetic characters and/or numbers. (No Spaces)" placeholder="bsmith29">

        Email:
            <input class="submissionfield" type="email" name="email" required placeholder="name@email.com" title="Example email address: tom@smith.com"> 

        Password:
            <input class="submissionfield" type="password" name="password" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" title="Password can only contain alphabetic characters and/or numbers. (No Spaces)" placeholder="Enter Password Here">


        Age:
            <input class="submissionfield" type="number" required pattern="[0-9]" title="Please enter your age, only numeric characters are allowed " name="age" required placeholder="Select your age &gt; &gt; ">

            Are you Male or Female?
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female


            What gender are your dogs?
                <input type="checkbox" name="gender_of_cats[]" value="male" checked> Male &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" name="gender_of_cats[]" value="female"> Female &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


    <div class="registration_form_complete">
        <input id ="registration_buttons" type="submit" value="Submit"> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: where does the php come into play? or are you asking us how to do it? which seems to be the case

Comment: I had PHP in there before, but removed it as it was  not working, so back to standard form...

Comment: use jquery for get and set the data and validate that data via php on server side also

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. Using AJAX API calls for validation allows you to notify the user something is wrong with a field before the form is posted. This is by far the most user friendly option.

If you really want to POST and let the server do all the validating in one go, there are 2 options. The main problem is that a POST will **reload the page**. So you need your server to respond to the POST with the new form-page, and **fill in the validated values on the server side** (so the user gets back the filled-in form.

The second way is to store the values in `localstorage` when you POST, and load them in again using javascript when you reload the page. However, in that case you don't get the validated values directly from the server, so I would **not** recommend this method.

Comment: I hope he renders his views in his server-side controller and not the traditional php upside-down way that is, a big php section inside the view file... (but even that with `isset()` checks would work :/ )

Comment: @SparK Yes, but the how and where to render HTML is a different fight ;) (although I also recommend using a templating language/system, PHP embedded in HTML is quite dirty)

Comment: PHP is a templating engine that grew too much. As long as there's no business logic besides rendering in the html view that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need Javascript for this. After the form submit the page will reload, so any information is lost by default. To store the values you could create a cookie before submiting the form and load these values onLoad() into the fields.

Comment: If the client has cookies disabled in the browser, this solution won't work. I recommend using the PHP $_SESSION[] variables to store the info after the form is submitted, and then read them when the form is reloaded.

Comment: And by storing the values client-side you can't get rid of the *invalid* data as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 <input class="submissionfield" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST?$_POST["name"]:""; ?>" required pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+" title="Your name can only contain alphabetic characters" placeholder="Bob Smith">
```